# How to calculate number of days per month, between two dates?

Tags: excel

I need to calculate number of days per month between two dates.

Does exists an Excel 2016 formula to do that ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Days or working days?

Comment: Days .. (all)...

Comment: I normally find that if the dates are entered and formatted correctly a simple subtraction works.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try on below formula.

```
=IF($D2>EOMONTH(DATEVALUE("01-"&LEFT(F$1,3)&"-"&YEAR($D2)),0),EOMONTH(DATEVALUE("01-"&LEFT(F$1,3)&"-"&YEAR($D2)),0),$D2)-IF($C2<DATEVALUE("01-"&LEFT(F$1,3)&"-"&YEAR($C2)),DATEVALUE("01-"&LEFT(F$1,3)&"-"&YEAR($C2)),$C2)+1
```

[image]

Comment: Put the formula in `F2` cell then `Drag` down and right as needed.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your `Month` row is text of the full name of the month.
That being the case, the following formula should work:

```
F2:  =SUM(N(TEXT(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,$C2):INDEX($A:$A,$D2)),"mmmm")=F$1))
```

- Then fill right to H2.
- Select `F2:H2` and fill down as far as needed.

*In some earlier versions of Excel, you may need to "confirm" this **array-formula** it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar*

[image]

**Algorithm**

- The `ROW(INDEX(...` formula creates an array of date numbers from beginning to end of the time period.
- The `TEXT` function then converts the serial date numbers to the Month, in the same full format as the month names in row 1.
- We then compare the months to the month in Row 1, and get an array of `TRUE/FALSE`.
- `N(` function converts that to an array of `0/1`,
- and we `SUM` the result.
- *Note that this formula will fail for dates later than 25 November 4770* :-)  Hopefully, that will not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a worksheet function `=NetworkDays.Intl()` where you can enter a start date, and end date, weekend days and holidays. This might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the first day of the next month, and subtract one day. That gives you the total number of days for the current month.

For March:

=DAY(H$2-1)

Make sure the answer is formatted as a number, not a date.

Cell H2 is where I entered the date.

[image: Formula Table]